# Ubuntu Touch: How to add other peoples calendars in the calendar core app?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, calendar

I am using the core app calendar (v0.4.600) with my bq Aquarius 4.5 ubuntu. Syncing to my google account works fine and I want to add some more calendars from other people. If I press "add calendar" I am guided to the system settings to add a new account. This is nonsense if you just want to add another google calendar (e.g. of my wife).
Any idea how to solve this problem? I want to have the calender also in the case of no internet connection!
I hope to get a solution which does not require to fiddle around with the console...I don't want to become an Ubuntu touch nerd ;-)

Regards
x8cr16

Comment: Here `add calendar` means `add a calendar account`. You can add another calendar from browser in google calendar web app. Just click the dropdown menu from `other calendar` & select `Add by url`. Then sync your phone with google. It should sync all the calendars including the one which you just added in google calendar. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The calendar app currently only supports syncing one calendar (the default calendar) per account. In the future you will be able to specify multiple calendars per account. As a workaround, you could try the google calendar webapp (as suggested). Alternatively you could create another account for the calendar you want to sync if you know the credentials.